# Syntax Error: SASS Duplicate key

Tags: sass

Is it not possibile to `@each` a list with duplicate keys like this :

```
@each $label, $value in (
        anthrazit: #7a7a7a,
        apricot: #ff8c00,
        beige: #deb887,
        blau: #0000cd,
        blaumelange: #0000cd,
        blauvintage: #0000cd,
        blau-gestreift: #0000cd,
        blau-grau: #0000cd,
        blau-kariert: #0000cd,
        bleached: #0000cd,
        bordeaux: #f00,
        bordeaux vintage: #f00,
        braun: #8b4513,
        braunvintage: #8b4513,
        braun-kariert: #8b4513,
        braun-melange: #8b4513,
        brickred: #f00,
        camel: #deb887,
        caramel: #8b4513,
        clean: #0000cd,
        coral: #f00,
        cream: #fffff0,
        denim: #0000cd,
        denimbleached: #0000cd,
        denimbraun: #8b4513,
        denimbraun used: #8b4513,
        denimclean: #0000cd,
        denimdarkwashed: #0000cd,
        denimdestroyed: #0000cd,
        denimgrau: #7a7a7a,
        denimgraubleached: #7a7a7a,
        denimgrauused: #7a7a7a,
        denimgrauwashed: #7a7a7a,
        denimschwarz: #000,
        denimschwarzused: #000,
        denimused: #0000cd,
        denimwashed: #0000cd,
        dunkelbraun: #8b4513,
        electricblue: #0000cd,
        flieder: #8b008b,
        fluogelb: #ff0,
        fluogruen: #228b22,
        fluopink: #ff1493,
        gelb: #ff0,
        grau: #7a7a7a,
        grauvintage: #7a7a7a,
        grau-melange: #7a7a7a,
        gruen: #228b22,
        gruenvintage: #228b22,
        gruen-kariert: #228b22,
        gruen-melange: #228b22,
        hellblau: #0000cd,
        hellblau vintage: #0000cd,
        hellgrau: #7a7a7a,
        hellgrau-melange: #7a7a7a,
        hellgruen: #228b22,
        iceblau: #0000cd,
        karoblau: #0000cd,
        karobraun: #8b4513,
        karogelb: #ff0,
        karograu: #7a7a7a,
        karogruen: #228b22,
        karolila: #8b008b,
        karopink: #ff1493,
        karorot: #f00,
        karoschwarz: #000,
        khaki: #228b22,
        lavendel: #8b008b,
        leder: #000,
        lila: #8b008b,
        mint: #228b22,
        mintvintage: #228b22,
        mittelblau: #0000cd,
        mocca: #8b4513,
        navy: #0000cd,
        navy: #0000cd,
        navyvintage: #0000cd,
        nude: #deb887,
        ocker-gelb: #ff0,
        oliv: #228b22,
        orange: #ff8c00,
        petrolblau: #0000cd,
        pinien-braun: #8b4513,
        pink: #ff1493,
        pink-kariert: #ff1493,
        powder-rose: #ff1493,
        rose: #ff1493,
        rosevintage: #ff1493,
        rose-melange: #ff1493,
        rot: #f00,
        rotvintage: #f00,
        rot-gestreift: #f00,
        rot-kariert: #f00,
        sand: #deb887,
        schwarz: #000,
        senf-gelb: #ff0,

        smaragdgruen: #228b22,
        streifenblau: #0000cd,
        streifenbraun: #8b4513,
        streifengruen: #228b22,
        streifennavy: #0000cd,
        streifenpink: #ff1493,
        streifenrot: #f00,
        streifenschwarz: #000,
        streifenweiss: #fffff0,
        taupe: #deb887,
        transparent: #fffff0,
        tuerkis: #40e0d0,
        weiss: #fffff0,
        weissvintage: #fffff0
) {
    .label-#{$label} {
        background: $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is what, exactly?

Comment: Syntax error: Duplicate key #000080 in map

Answer (score 1):

Color names are not strings, they are colors and treated the same as a hex/rgb/rgba/hsl/hsla color declaration.  The color that is equal to `#000080` is `navy`.  You have duplicate keys for navy.

In the future, if you are expecting the keys for your mappings to be strings, you should always force them to be strings by using quotes.